# perl -p -i -e replace line with text containing symbol

Tags: linux, bash, perl, symbols, substitution

In a linux Vm, I am trying to change the second line of 50+ files.

I have used this command below successfully for strings without symbols.

```
perl -p -i -e 's/.*/new_line / if $.==2' .
```

However now I am trying to add the new string  " # $new_line $ " using this command :

```
perl -p -i -e 's/.*/# $Header$ / if $.==2' .
```

But getting the following error:

```
Final $ should be \$ or $name at -e line 1, within string
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/.*/# $Header$ /"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use: `perl -pie 's/.*/# \$Header\$/ if $.==2'`

Comment: Thanks Bunch Anuchava, it worked!  :) perl -pie 's/.*/# \$Header\$ / if $.==2' .

Comment: @anubhava's example pretty much works, except it replaces two lines with one because the `s///` doesn't replace the "\n" at the end of the string.

Comment: @AndyLester `.*` doesn't match the newline

Comment: @ysth: My mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava: That `-pie` won't do what you want.  Perl takes the `-ie` to mean that you want to replace in place, and to add `e` to the end of each backup file's name.  You have to do `perl -pi -e` or `perl -p -i -e`.

Comment: Thanks @AndyLester, I rarely use perl command line and those were the reasons why I left a comment not an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong:

```
Final $ should be \$ or $name at -e line 1, within string
```

You need to escape the `$`s.  It is seeing the second `$` as part of a variable, but it's not.

You'll also need to escape the first `$` because Perl sees `$Header` as a variable, and will substitute the value of `$Header` instead of the actual string `$Header`.  Since `$Header` has no value, you'll just get an empty string.

You also can't specify `.` as the files to operate on.  `.` is a directory, and Perl will tell you that if you try to use it as a file:

```
Can't do inplace edit: . is not a regular file.
```

You also want to use the `-l` flag to make sure that Perl handles line endings correctly.  When you replace the entire string with your new string, you're not including the `\n` at the end.

So what you want is:

```
perl -l -p -i -e 's/.*/# \$Header\$ / if $.==2' *.html
```

(replace `*.html` with your own filespec)

Finally, you could also just replace the working variable `$_` with the string you want, rather than using the `s///`, like so:

```
perl -l -p -i -e '$_ = q{# $Header$} if $.==2'  *
```

`q{xyz}` is the same as `'xyz'`, where no interpolation is done.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I understand now! got it to work :)